# Why is CreateManagedControl access-violating after upgrading from .Net 4.6.1 to .Net 5?

Tags: mfc, controls, c++-cli, upgrade, .net-5

I have an MFC app containing a C++/CLI project that calls `MFC::CWinFormsControl<MyWidget>::CreateManagedControl()` to create a control written in C#.
This worked fine under .Net Framework 4.6.1, but now I have upgraded the C++/CLI and C# projects to .Net 5 it causes an access violation:

```
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFC81A3F528 (clr.dll) in MyApp.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000000.
```

Stack trace:

```
mfc140ud.dll!COleControlSite::CreateControlCommon(CWnd * pWndCtrl, const _GUID & clsid, const CControlCreationInfo & creationInfo, const wchar_t * lpszWindowName, unsigned long dwStyle, const tagPOINT * ppt, const tagSIZE * psize, unsigned int nID, CFile * pPersist, int bStorage, wchar_t * bstrLicKey) Line 224 C++
mfc140ud.dll!COleControlSite::CreateControl(CWnd * pWndCtrl, const CControlCreationInfo & creationInfo, unsigned long dwStyle, const tagPOINT * ppt, const tagSIZE * psize, unsigned int nID) Line 198  C++
mfc140ud.dll!COleControlContainer::CreateControlCommon(CWnd * pWndCtrl, const _GUID & clsid, const CControlCreationInfo & creationInfo, const wchar_t * lpszWindowName, unsigned long dwStyle, const tagPOINT * ppt, const tagSIZE * psize, unsigned int nID, CFile * pPersist, int bStorage, wchar_t * bstrLicKey, COleControlSite * * ppNewSite) Line 301 C++
mfc140ud.dll!COleControlContainer::CreateControl(CWnd * pWndCtrl, const CControlCreationInfo & creationInfo, unsigned long dwStyle, const tagPOINT * ppt, const tagSIZE * psize, unsigned int nID) Line 270 C++
mfc140ud.dll!CWnd::CreateControl(const CControlCreationInfo & creationInfo, unsigned long dwStyle, const tagPOINT * ppt, const tagSIZE * psize, CWnd * pParentWnd, unsigned int nID) Line 90    C++
[Managed to Native Transition]  
CLI.dll!Microsoft::VisualC::MFC::CWinFormsControl<Widget::MyWidget>::InternalCreateManagedControl(CControlCreationInfo& info, unsigned int dwStyle, tagRECT& rect, CWnd* pParentWnd, int nID) Line 122  C++
CLI.dll!Microsoft::VisualC::MFC::CWinFormsControl<Widget::MyWidget>::CreateManagedControl(System::Type^ pType, unsigned int dwStyle, tagRECT& rect, CWnd* pParentWnd, int nID) Line 133 C++
CLI.dll!Microsoft::VisualC::MFC::CWinFormsControl<Widget::MyWidget>::CreateManagedControl(unsigned int dwStyle, tagRECT& rect, CWnd* pParentWnd, int nID) Line 149  C++
CLI.dll!Cli::CreateControl(CWnd* parent, int id) Line 191   C++
```

Other C# functionality works without a hitch, as does an experimental `gcnew Widget::MyWidget()`.  I've been experimenting with project settings for some time but am getting nowhere.  Any ideas?

Comment: Did you find an answer to this, I am having similar problems, .net 4.8, MFC app that I want to extend using .NET forms (it's faster to code in Forms than MFC)

Comment: Sorry @DanielMošmondor, I ended up doing other things so didn't get to the bottom of this.  All I can tell you is that after a smaller upgrade to .Net Framework 4.7.2 it did still work.

Comment: np, for now i made it (started a winforms control under mfc app).  I'll try to take it from there and see how that goes.